# NSURL, creating pdfs

Tags: iphone, pdf, nsurl

I'm trying to create some pdfs from pdfs added to my iphone as an exercise for myself in quartz and just getting better with the language.  So I have this so far to get the multiple pdfs on my phone:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:&error];
    NSArray *onlyPDFs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.pdf'"]];
```

How can I convert this to a NSURL object, or an array of NSURL objects?  I've tried some different things like URLForResource, initWithString, but I don't think those are correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to generate an NSURL for each PDF in onlyPDFs:

```
for (NSString *p in onlyPDFs) {
    NSString *name = [p stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"pdf"];
}
```